# How to upload a file to AWS S3 subfolder using python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file to a subfolder in a Bucket in AWS S3.
I am using the code given below.

```
filename  = '/tmp/' + 'image' + '.png'
file_obj = open(filename, 'rb')
s3_upload = s3.put_object( Bucket="aaa/Bbb/cc-cc", Key="filename.png", Body=file_obj)
   
return
    {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps("Executed Successfully"
    }
```

The above concept of uploading files to a subfolder of AWS S3 Bucket works fine in `Node.js` but when implemented in `python` then it gives the following error.

```
Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid bucket name \"aaa/Bbb/cc-cc\": Bucket name must match the regex \"^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]{1,255}$\" or be an ARN matching the regex \"^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,63}$\"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case bucket name is just `aaa`, while `/Bbb/cc-cc` should be part of the keyname:

```
s3_upload = s3.put_object( Bucket="aaa", Key="/Bbb/cc-cc/filename.png", Body=file_obj)
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980652/how-to-get-aws-s3-object-location-url-using-pyhton-3-8