# How to get AWS S3 object Location/URL using python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am uploading a file to AWS S3 using AWS Lambda function (Python3.8) with the following code.

```
   file_obj = open(filename, 'rb')

   s3_upload = s3.put_object( Bucket="aaa", Key="aaa.png", Body=file_obj)
   
   return {
   'statusCode': 200,
   'body': json.dumps("Executed Successfully")
   }
```

I want to get the location/url of the S3 object in `return`. In `Node.js` we use the `.location` parameter for getting the object location/url.

Any idea how to do this using python 3.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url of S3 objects has **known format** and follows [Virtual hosted style access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html):

```
https://bucket-name.s3.Region.amazonaws.com/keyname
```

Thus, you can construct the url yourself:

```
bucket_name = 'aaa'
aws_region = boto3.session.Session().region_name
object_key = 'aaa.png'

s3_url = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.{aws_region}.amazonaws.com/{object_key}"

return {
   'statusCode': 200,
   'body': json.dumps({'s3_url': s3_url})
}
```

Comment: It's returning `null`

Comment: It was some issue on my end. It's working fine now.
Thanks for your help.