# Access Location when uploading File to AWS S3 using @aws-sdk/lib-storage

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I'm currently in the process of upgrading my project from SDK v2 to V3 and I'm struggling to access the location URL of the file I'm uploading to my S3 bucket.

Currently the below implementation is unable to access `location` since it does not exist within the `AbortMultipartUploadCommandOutput` response type.

```
try {
    const x = new Upload({
      client: new S3Client({ region: "us-east-2" }),
      params: {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: filename.toString(),
        Body: buffer
      }
    })


    const response = await x.done()
    
    const locationUrl = response.location

    return locationUrl

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

Another solution I've been exploring is using `PutObjectCommand`.

```
const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `${path}/${fileName}`,
    Body: fileContent,
    ContentType: "text/csv"
  })
```

What are the possible solutions to gaining access to my file's information once it has been uploaded onto S3?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980652/how-to-get-aws-s3-object-location-url-using-python-3-8
You might not actually need the url in output as you can construct it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

you can narrow the `result` returned by `upload.done()` and access to the properties.

```js
function isComplete(
    output:
      | CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput
      | AbortMultipartUploadCommandOutput,
  ): output is CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput {
    return (output as CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput).ETag !== undefined;
  }
```

```js
const result = await upload.done();
if (isComplete(result)) {
  const key = result.Key;
  const location = result.Location;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`const response = await x.done()` return type is `CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput| AbortMultipartUploadCommandOutput`, Location details is returned in CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput you can do it like this

```
      const data: CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput = await parallelUploads3.done();
      if (!data.Location) {
        throw new Error('Location not found');
      }
      return data.Location;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create by yourself if response 200

```
location = https://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${Key}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

client

```
const config: S3ClientConfig = {
  region: "us-east-2",
  maxAttempts: 10,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: access_key_id,
    secretAccessKey: secret_access_key,
  },
};

export const s3 = () => new S3(config) || new S3Client(config);
```

upload function

```
try {
    const x = new Upload({
client: s3(),
queueSize: 4,
leavePartsOnError: false,
params: {
  ACL: "public-read",
  ContentType: "image/jpeg",
  Key,
  Body: file,
  Bucket: AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
},
})


    const response = await x.done()
    
    const locationUrl = response.location

    return locationUrl

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```